# Definition of the order of a Lie group

Tags: group-theory, definition, lie-groups

My textbook ("Mathematical Methods for Physicists", George B. Arfken) says the following when talking about SO(2):

> The dimension of this vector space (over the complex numbers) is the
>   order of G, that is, the number of linearly independent generators of
>   the group. (page 247)

However, I cannot seem to find such a definition anywhere else. For finite groups, I know that order is equal to the number of elements, so continuous (Lie) groups must have infinite cardinals for their order.
Could someone please elucidate on the different definitions?

Comment: Vector space ? is it referring to SO(2) ? as far as I know SO(2) is diffeomorphic to a circle and is not a linear space. Would you clarify this ? I think the passage refers to the tangent space of SO(2).

Comment: The "order" should be "dimension". It is the dimension of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ of $SO(2)$, which is indeed a vector space dimension. This coincides with the dimension of $SO(2)$ as a Lie group, i.e., as a manifold. See for example [here](http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~yangob/groups.pdf).

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh Sorry, it is indeed referring to the algebra so(2).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, that clarifies it. Your example notes are also really useful.